# why mobile page flickering on load - using jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making a app using jquerymobile. i am always getting flickering effect while my page load. for example i have a custom font on the page, all load before the custom font loads, again, all get refreshing, and i am getting back all elements back.

for a experiement, i made my function to hide the body.

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $('body').hide();
})
```

but while load the page, still i can see the video (some time contents which loading after video) a second, and the 'body' hiding this. it means, i understand, even before my function call up (mentioned above), the page start to load, so after a second of time delayed my function works. it annoying to see the page at all. i am using HTML5 mobile boilerplate. but when i remove the mobile jquery all are good.

how to fix this? what is the problem with my side?

my order of js linked (before closing tag of body) :

```
        <script src="js/vendor/zepto.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/helper.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```